# Adding custom names to a GeoPandas legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, geopandas

I have a shapefile which has an attribute table with a column I would like to make a map/plot of. The attribute values are numerical (integer). I have made two dicts to map the colors and names I want to these integers.

```
Palette = {0: 'black',
           20: '#FFBB22',
           30: '#FFFF4C',
           40: '#F096FF',
           80: '#0032C8',
           90: '#0096A0',
           112: '#009900',
           114: '#00CC00',
           116: '#007800',
           124: '#A0DC00',
           126:'#648C00'}

names  = {0: 'NAN',
           20: 'Shrubs',
           30: 'Herbaceous',
           40: 'Cultivated',
           80: 'Permanent Water',
           90: 'Herbaceous Wetland',
           112: 'Closed Forest: Evergreen',
           114: 'Closed Forest: Deciduous broad leaf',
           116: 'Closed forest: Other',
           124: 'Open forest: Deciduous broad leaf',
           126:'Open forest: Other'}
```

However, while I can map the colors to the right values, I cannot get the legend to show the right names. The legend comes up empty and I get a message that "No handles with labels found to put in legend"

My code is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))

# Loop through each attribute value and assign each
# with the correct color & width specified in the dictionary
for ctype, data in map_df.groupby('landcovermode'):
    color = Palette[ctype]
    label = names[ctype]
    data.plot(color=color,
          ax=ax,
          label=label,legend=True)


# Place legend in the lower right hand corner of the plot
ax.legend(loc='lower right',
      fontsize=15,
      frameon=True)

ax.set_axis_off()
```

How do I get the legend to read my labels from the dict?

Answer (score 0):

The [official reference](https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html#from-longitudes-and-latitudes) has been edited to address your question. I'm still new to geopandas and had a hard time with it. For the target points I wanted to draw, I could handle the colors in the list, but I couldn't handle the legend labels in the list. So I created a temporary gdf for each case and created the graph. The data format is data frame and list, but I think it can be supported.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'City': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 'Caracas'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Venezuela'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86]})

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
colors = ['blue','green','red','black','yellow']

ax = world[world.continent == 'South America'].plot(color='white', edgecolor='black', figsize=(10,10))

for idx, row in gdf.iterrows():
    tmp = df.iloc[idx].to_frame().T
    gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(tmp, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(tmp.Longitude, tmp.Latitude))
    gdf.plot(ax=ax, color=colors[idx], label=row['City'], markersize=100, legend=True)

ax.legend(loc='lower right', fontsize=12, frameon=True) 
ax.set_axis_off()

plt.show()
```

[image]